# Possible loss of precision and symbol errors in Java

Tags: java

This is the line of code I'm trying to make work:

```
 if (rend > num) rend = num;
```

But Dr.Java spits out this error:

```
File: /Users/spencer/Downloads/MergeTDNonrecursive.java  [line: 75]
Error: /Users/spencer/Downloads/MergeTDNonrecursive.java:75: possible loss of precision
found   : long
required: int
```

Similarly,

```
sort(a, aux, 0, a.length-1);
```

is prompting the error:

```
    File: /Users/spencer/Downloads/MergeTDNonrecursive.java  [line: 106]
Error: /Users/spencer/Downloads/MergeTDNonrecursive.java:106: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method sort(java.lang.Comparable[],java.lang.Comparable[],int,int)
location: class MergeTDNonrecursive
```

I've searched hi and lo (lol), but in all seriousness I can't see what's going wrong with my code.

EDIT: I should mention that I don't know the difference between long and int, specifically because I don't know what long is. How can I remedy this in my code? And no, these errors are popping up when I try to compile.

Comment: As the message error says, you can have a precision loss when putting a long in an int variable. If you're sure it's OK, cast.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza No, they're `long` and `int`.

Comment: How are you even assigning an int to a long? Does that code compile?

Comment: @dystroy What would I need to include to have this cast and be accepted?

Comment: *"I don't know the difference between long and int"*. READ the documentation.

Answer (score 3):

The error message is quite specific: You're apparently trying to assign a variable with a larger range (`long`) to one with a smaller range (`int`), and Java requires you to specifically okay the restriction with a cast.

If you have

```
int rend;
long num;
```

there's a chance that the value in `num` is too big to fit in `rend`. You can tell Java that it's okay to possibly lose information by saying this:

```
rend = (int) num;
```

However, this is usually a logical error, and you should address why the two variables are of differing sizes.

The `cannot find symbol` isn't "similar", it's a completely different error, and it's because you're calling `sort`, but no `sort` method exists.

Comment: I'm not all too familiar with the terminology. How do I cast and what is that?

Comment: @user3112563: If the error message is correct, and we assume it is, then `rend` is an `int` and `num` is a `long`. Either change the code to make `rend` a `long` or `num` an `int`, or cast the assignment like so: `rend=(int)num` (which is almost surely a mistake due to the loss of precision).